# Windows 10 Universal App Bluetooth Low Energy getting data

Tags: arduino, win-universal-app, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a Genuino 101 Board and I want to receive data from its BLE. How can I do that in Universal App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to pair the devices first, so the receiving party can see the BLE device. While pairing the BLE device profile is cached, and this cached information is used later on when the code tries to connect to the BLE device, so do make sure your BLE service is fully on while pairing.

Then after you locate the device via DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync , then you can use GattDeviceService.FromIdAsync() to get the service, which implements the interface for finding the BLE characteristics

For more information [check my blog](http://www.drjukka.com/blog/wordpress/?p=167) article on the topic. Fully functional example available there as well.